# Retornar ultimo nível de uma tabela com auto relacionamento(RECURSIVO)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela(Correio) com auto relacionamento
Exemplo

[image: Tabela Correio]

e gostaria de retornar o ultimo valor inserido de acordo com o status de outra tabela(CorreioStatus) que relaciona com ela

[image: Tabela Tipo]

```
SELECT MAX( id )
  FROM Correio
  WHERE id NOT IN
 (SELECT IdCorreioPai
  FROM Correio C
    INNER JOIN CorreioTipo CU ON CU.IdCorreio = C.IdCorreio

  WHERE C.IdCorreioPai IS NOT NULL AND CU.IdStatus = 1
  )
  GROUP BY IdCorreioPai
```

Comment: se quer uma query recursiva, pq não cria uma function ou procedure que chama ela mesma e resolve a recursividade?

Comment: @RicardoPontual então, eu não sou muito bom de banco de dados, tentei fazer via entity framework porem não consegui, procurei algum exemplo aqui para tentar entender não consegui achar nada do tipo.